# Get current location when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I have a google maps app and now I've added a button. I want to get a message (Toast) with my coordinates when I click the button. Which is the simplest way to do this? Do I also have to implement onLocationChanged class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different ways to implement it. I tend to think that the best for your task is to show toast after pressing my location button.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
     private GoogleMap mMap;

     /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Show my location button
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                //Do something with your location. You can use mMap.getMyLocation(); 
                //anywhere in this class to get user location 
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, String.format("%f : %f",
                        mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude()), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also you can show toast with user location every time it changes. To do it set OnMyLocationChangeListener

```
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(android.location.Location location) {
            //...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I also have to implement onLocationChanged class?

If you don't want to receive location updates, the answer is no.

> Which is the simplest way to do this?

The simplest way is to obtain the last known location as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Example Google maps project on [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples) has an example of how to do this.

Additionally, Android Studio has a Google Maps Activity template you can choose when you create a project.  This project has `getLastKnownLocation()` implemented.  More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).